# How to remove from staging without actually deleting

Tags: git

I've read all of the articles but I'm still confused.

I was trying to force Git to release a file as I couldn't commit.  I think the original problem was caused by making a commit and then closing my text editor before writing a commit message.  To solve it I `cd` to the home directory and did a `force` command.

My problem is I forgot to `cd` back into my repro and did `git add .` adding all of my websites and repros.

Now when I do `git status` I see all of the files

If I do `git reset` I see the files when I do `git status` they are marked as `untracked files`.

If I `checkout` an old `commit` I still see the files when I do `git status` still marked as untracked files.

How can I reset `staging` so there are no files there, but I don't delete my entire home directory.

I know I'll get marked down for this but I'm petrified of deleting all those files.  To confirm, although I navigated out of the repository, I think the `.git` file is in the repository.  So I should be able to simply delete or rename that file right?

Comment: What do you mean by "see the files there"?  If you do `git reset`, the files you inadvertently added are no longer tracked.

Comment: I did git reset and then I did git status and I still see them

Comment: You see them when?  When you run `ls`?  That's good, because you don't want them deleted.  When you run `git status`, git reports that they are untracked.

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing the list of files and the header "Untracked files:" has scrolled off the top of your output device.

Comment: "I'm petrified of deleting all those files." - make a manual backup before issuing any more git commands perhaps

Comment: Yes, they are untracked files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have done a `git init` before the `git add .`.

To undo this before doing any real harm, just remove the `.git` directory and all of its contents in your home directory.

As noted from @torek,

> The work-tree remains undisturbed and is now just an ordinary set of
>   directories/folders/whatever-you-like-to-call-these full of ordinary
>   files.

Answer (score 4):

This whole thing is a little tricky (and is one reason I never use Git for my home directory—I store my dot-files in Git, for instance, but do this via symlink or copy, so that the repository is not *in* my home directory).

It's important to remember, when dealing with Git, that there are *three* places for files.  One of the three is a permanent store, a sort of database in which your files are kept frozen for all time and you can always get them back.<sup>1</sup>  These are the *commits*.  No part of any existing commit can *ever* be changed, and that includes the files that are stored as full snapshots within each commit.  (See footnote 1.)

But there are two other places that Git stores files, and that matters.  It's particularly important when you realize that the frozen files inside Git are in a special, compressed, Git-only format.  So these files are completely useless to anything that's *not* Git, and moreover, you—and even Git—can't *change* them.  That means Git needs to have a way to take the files *out* of the commits, and put them back in their normal, everyday, usable form.

That way—and that place—is your *work-tree*.  Your work-tree holds the everyday usable form of your files.  Git will copy files *out* of commits, *overwriting* whatever is in your work-tree, as needed.  It will also *remove* files from your work-tree when that seems appropriate.

What *this* means is that files in your work-tree are *not* permanent.  But they *are* useful—unlike Git's special frozen copies—and it's very tempting to make your work-tree not just your "play" area but your practical, every-day, get-things-done area.  There's nothing inherently wrong with this, but you have to accept the idea that Git will then be able to reach in and fuss with this area, and understand when, how, and why Git does this.

In between the commit database and your work-tree, Git stores a *third* copy of each file.  This third copy is in the frozen *format*, but isn't frozen.  This third copy is what Git calls, variously, the *index* or the *staging area*.  Git makes all *new* commits from its index.

As with the work-tree, things in the index are *not* permanent.  In fact, they *must* not be permanent: if they were you couldn't change them!  But, being impermanent, if you *remove* them, they really are gone.  That's true for both the index copies of files, and for the work-tree copies.<sup>2</sup>

When you run `git commit`, Git simply packages up all the files that are in the index *right then* and makes a commit out of them.  (The commit also adds your name and email address, the date-and-time stamp, and so on, but the *files* that are now stored permanently, frozen into the commit, are those from the index.)

You can, at any time, run:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

to tell Git: *remove the given <file> from the index, while not removing it from the work-tree.*  The file is now, at this point, *not* in the index.  But it may be in some existing *commits*.  You can now make *new* commits and the new commits won't contain the file—because it's not in your index.

If you check out some *old* commit, though ... well, `git checkout` works by:<sup>3</sup>

- copying the commit to the index, then
- copying the index to the work-tree

so that you have all your files from that commit available, both in the index (for a new commit that you might make in a moment, based on the old commit) and in the work-tree (so that you can see and work with your files).

Suppose you have a file named `F` in that commit, that's not in your index *before* the `git checkout`, but is in your work-tree.  You then run `git checkout <that-commit>`, and now `F` *is* in your index, and also is in your work-tree.  The work-tree copy now (probably) matches the commit's copy (see footnote 3 about "probably").  If you now decide that you're done looking at the old commit, and use `git checkout master` to get back to modern times, Git will *remove* file `F` from your index ... and therefore also *remove* file `F` from your work-tree.

File `F`, not being in your index, goes back to being *untracked*, except for the huge problem that it's *gone from your work-tree*, so it's not even there: its untracked-ness is irrelevant.  There *are* copies of `F` in old commits—it's in the commit you had out a moment ago after all—and maybe those are good enough:

```
git show <hash>:F
```

will let you view the copy that's in the given commit, and you can redirect its output to `F` to re-create it in the work-tree.

There is no perfect cure for this problem—well, except for one: move the Git repository elsewhere.  Make this work area *not* be a Git work-tree.  Git won't control it in any way anymore, and therefore won't remove or clobber files that are in it.  The main real problem is historic commits that have files that you want them not to have.  You *cannot* change those commits.  You *can* copy them to new-and-improved commits that don't have the files.  See, e.g., [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/872565/1256452) and everything in the tag [bfg-repo-cleaner](/questions/tagged/bfg-repo-cleaner), for instance.  If you do use these, make sure you don't mix the new repository, with its new and improved commits, together with the old-and-lousy repository with the bad commits: Git is geared to glomming all commits together and will "want" to leave you with a repository that has *both* sets of commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you *can* get rid of a commit.  You do this by making it so that you cannot *find* the commit by any branch or tag name or any other name.  Git will notice that the commit cannot be reached—see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) for a good discussion of *reachability*—and will eventually throw it out of the database, and then *those* copies of the files will be gone.  But all the reachable commits will remain, and they will hold copies of the files as well.

Because the files in each commit are frozen, commits get to *share* them when they are unchanged.  So if you make a million commits, all of which store a 4000 line file, but the 4000 line file is the *same* in all the million commits, there's really just one copy of the file, even though there are a million commits that all have that copy.  So the fact that every commit stores *every* file doesn't make the commit-database explode in size: they store via sharing.

<sup>2</sup>There may, or may not, be some way *outside* Git to get work-tree files back.  For instance, MacOS offers its Time Machine.  But *Git* doesn't know how to work that, and this is about what Git does.

<sup>3</sup>This is very much simplified.  See [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for most of the gory details.  There's even more to know if you have *filter drivers* defined.

Comment: Thanks you, very thorough.  Can you do do a `git rm --cached .` to remove all files?  Are you in agreement that deleting the .git folder solves my problem (I'm not worried about this particular repro.

Comment: (1) You could indeed use `git rm --cached .` to remove all files (well, those at the current directory and below) from the index. Done at the top level, that would mean your next commit would be a commit containing no files at all. There's not much use for such a commit.

Comment: (2) Yes, if you remove (as in `rm -rf`) the `.git` directory, the repository itself is entirely gone. The work-tree remains undisturbed and is now just an ordinary set of directories/folders/whatever-you-like-to-call-these full of ordinary files.